# How to reference public bitbucket repo as npm module in package.json on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, npm, bitbucket

I tried `{myrepo}: git://git@bitbucket.org/{myaccount}/{myrepo}.git` in packages.json. On my local machine when I type `sudo npm install` (I have to use `sudo`) it works and my repo is cloned to node_modules.

When I am pushing my app to heroku there are errors:

```
       npm ERR! git clone git://git@bitbucket.org/{myaccount}/{myrepo}.git Initialized empty Git repository in /app/.npm/_git-remotes/git-git-bitbucket-org-{myaccount}-{myrepo}-git-bd17f867/
       npm ERR! git clone git://git@bitbucket.org/{myaccount}/{myrepo}.git 
       npm ERR! git clone git://git@bitbucket.org/{myaccount}/{myrepo}.git fatal: Unable to look up git@bitbucket.org (Unknown host)
       npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: Unable to look up git@bitbucket.org (Unknown host)
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
       npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
       npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
       npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
       npm ERR!     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
       npm ERR!     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
       npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
       npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

This is PUBLIC repo.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Try to use `git+https://bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}.git` instead.

Or `git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}.git` if you want to fetch it over ssh, but I wouldn't recommend it, since it requires auth.

Answer (score 0):

@alex's answer was working for me previously, but today I had to update the url to use `bitbucket:{user}/{repo}` - and make sure the package.json has the `"name"` field correct.